# Keep container view on screen throughout segue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicontainerview

I want to keep a container view on the screen while I do Push segues. Like what the YouTube video player does on the iOS app. Any view you push to go to, the video player view stays on the screen. I don't even know where to start really. I'm not using auto-layout.

Answer (score 1):

A good start would be to think about the view hierarchy you're trying to achieve. Consider the following (top -> down == front -> back):

```
- Top Container (optional but probably recommended)
  - Video View
  - Navigation Container
    - Tab 1
      - Subviews
      - More subviews
    - Tab 2
      - Subviews
    - Tab 3
      - Another Container
        - Subviews
```

The `Top Container` could be anything you want. Perhaps a `UINavigationController` but really, it's up to you. This controller would take care of managing what is on screen, aka video is on or off, and/or receive any kind of information from it's `Navigation Container` through delegation.

Your question is not precise enough for me to go into details but this should get you started.